# Kakutani's Lemma

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

I read this story a while ago, and I'm wondering whether there's any proof that it is true or whether it's just made up?

> One day Shizuo Kakutani…was teaching a class at Yale. He wrote down a
>   lemma on the blackboard and announced that the proof was obvious. One
>   student timidly raised his hand and said that it wasn’t obvious to
>   him. Could Kakutani explain? After several moments’ thought, Kakutani
>   realized that he could not himself prove the lemma. He apologized, and
>   said that he would report back at their next class meeting.
>
> After class, Kakutani, went straight to his office. He labored for
>   quite a time and found that he could not prove the pesky lemma. He
>   skipped lunch and went to the library to track down the lemma. After
>   much work, he finally found the original paper. The lemma was stated
>   clearly and succinctly. For the proof, the author had written,
>   “Exercise for the reader.” The author of this 1941 paper was Kakutani.

Comment: Various versions of this joke are told about various mathematicians. In one version, the lecturer after 10 minutes of thinking finally says: "Yes, it is indeed obvious".

Comment: Wikipedia says K. published his fixed-point theorem in 1941. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @Spencer did you check that paper yourself? It is short and no lemma in it is left as an exercise.

Comment: @KCd behind a paywall? No way. Anyway, if the story is apocryphal there wouldn't be an exercise left for the reader.

Comment: @Spencer there are ways of getting around a paywall (heard of Sci-Hub?).